# How to delete multiple sheets using input box

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, delete-file, inputbox

Just need some help. I want to delete multiple sheets using their partial name that I will enter in the input box. Is there any code that I can add multiple partial names in input box so they will be deleted at once?

For example, I would like to add these partial names: "Pivot", "IWS, "Associate", "Split", and "Invoice"
My initial code can delete sheets with just one partial name, sample if I enter "Pivot" it will delete all sheets with "Pivot" name. I want to tweak my code where I can add multiple partial name to the input box.

**Here's the initial code:**

```
Sub ClearAllSheetsSpecified()
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Clear all sheets specified in input box
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Dim shName As String
   Dim xName As String
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   Dim cnt As Integer
   shName = Application.InputBox("Enter the sheet name to delete:", "Delete sheets", _
                                   ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name, , , , , 2)
   If shName = "" Then Exit Sub
   '**** use LCase() here
   xName = "*" & LCase(shName) & "*"
'    MsgBox xName
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   cnt = 0
   For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       '**** Use LCase() here
       If LCase(xWs.Name) Like xName Then
           xWs.Delete
           'MsgBox xName
           cnt = cnt + 1
       End If
   Next xWs
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   MsgBox "Have deleted " & cnt & " worksheets", vbInformation, "Sheets removed"
```

I'm looking for a code that I can enter any partial name in my input box then sheets will be deleted as long as they exist in my current WB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to capture your list of phrases.  The input text must have a common delimiter that you code for.  In this case I used the semi-colon.

```
Sub testIt()
        Dim shName As String
        Dim xName() As String
        Dim cnt As Integer
        shName = Application.InputBox("Enter the sheet names (delimited by ;) to delete:", "Delete sheets", _
                                        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name, , , , , 2)
        If shName = "" Then Exit Sub
        '**** use LCase() here
        xName = Split(LCase(shName), ";")
        For x = 0 To UBound(xName)
                Debug.Print "*" & xName(x) & "*"
                'do your delete
        Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @igittr, thanks for the code! I tried your code but the sheets were not deleted. I tried different entry with semicolon delimiter like IWS;Associate;Pivot even a format with spaces in between IWS ; Associate ; Pivot and the exact names.  Nothing happened. :(

The existing sheet name: 
3362849_Associate Hours
3362849_Pivot Table
3362849_IWS

Comment: You do still have the loop through the WB Sheets looking for those that are "like" these phrases, true?  If your delete loop worked before, it should still do the trick.